# How generate multiple random distribution from a vector of mean and st.dev in octave/matlab?

Tags: matlab, random, statistics, octave, normal-distribution

So I have a vector V of values  with dimension [5,1]. For each value in this vector V[i] I would like to generate let's say 5 numbers normally distributed  with mean V[i] and a fixed st deviation. So in the end I will have a matrix [5,5] which on the i-row has 5 values normally distributed  with mean V[i]. How can i do this with octave/matlab  without using for loop ? Practically I would like to pass to the normrnd function a vector of means V and get a set of n normally distributed number for each mean in the vector V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `normrnd` with array input

You can turn the vector of means into a matrix and pass it to `normrnd`. This works because, as explained in [`normrnd`'s documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html),

> `r = normrnd(mu,sigma)` [...]
>
> To generate random numbers from multiple distributions, specify `mu` and `sigma` using arrays. If both `mu` and `sigma` are arrays, then the array sizes must be the same. If either `mu` or `sigma` is a scalar, then `normrnd` expands the scalar argument into a constant array of the same size as the other argument. Each element in `r` is the random number generated from the distribution specified by the corresponding elements in `mu` and `sigma`.

Example:

```
mu = [30; 15; 7; -60; 0]; % vector of means
std = 2;                  % common standard deviation
N = 4;                    % number of samples for each mean
result = normrnd(repmat(mu(:), 1, N), std);
```

### Using `randn` with implicit expansion

You can generate a matrix with samples from a standard Gaussian distribution, mutiply by the desired standard deviation, and add the desired mean to each row:

```
result = mu(:) + std*randn(numel(mu), N);
```

This works because

- changing the standard deviation of a zero-mean Gausian distribution is equivalent to scaling;
- changing the mean of a Gaussian distribution is equivalent to shifting.

The shifting is done using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). This approach avoids building the intermediate matrix of repeated means from the previous approach, and calls `randn` instead of `normrnd`, so it may be more efficient.

Comment: Just adding that for the `normrnd` function in octave you would also have to load the `statistics` package :)